# Substraction between two columns of different SELECTs

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two differente SELECTs with different conditions but the same columns.

Imagin that I have this:

[image: selects]

So what I want to do is to substract the amount of the first table to the amount of the second table (where both IDs match and the date differs by one month) to know the delta between them.

This is a very simple explanation, but the data model and the extraction is pretty difficult, so this is the only way I can afford this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the left join as follows:

```
select s1.id, s1.date d1, s2.date d2, s1.value - s2.value as delta
from subquery1 s1 
left join subquery2 s2
on s1.id = s2.id
and add_months(s1.date,-1) = s2.date
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming date difference can be either ways

```
select t1.id,t2.id, T1.DT, t2.dt, t1.amt,t2.amt, t1.amt-t2.amt diff 
from t1, t2
where t1.id=t2.id 
and abs(MONTHS_BETWEEN(t1.dt, t2.dt)) = 1
```